# Dual Norm of a max function.

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to find the dual norm of 
$$\|(x,y)\|_K=\max\{|x|,|y|,|x-y|\}.$$
I have obtained $\|(x',y')\|_K^* = |x'|+|y'|$, but don't think that this is correct.
I obtained this as follows :
$$K = \{(x,y)\in R^n : \max\{|x|,|y|,|x-y|\} \leq 1\}$$
$$|(x,y).(x',y')| = |xx' + yy'| \leq |x||x'|+|y||y'| \leq \max\{|x-y|,|x|,|y|\}(|x'|+|y'|) \leq |x'|+|y'|,$$
thus concluding that $\|(x',y')\|_K^* = |x'| + |y'|$.
I don't think that this is correct because I know that this is the dual norm of $\max\{|x|,|y|\}$.

Comment: What is your definition of dual norm?

Comment: The definition I have is $\|(x,y)\|^*=\sup_{\|(x',y')\|=1}|(x,y).(x',y')|$.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to answer this, be it a very brief answer or not.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question, but it would help others if you explained how you obtained $\|(x',y')\|^*_K = |x'| + |y'|$ and why you don't think it is correct.